# If $\frac{f(x^2)}{f(x)}=1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^7$ then what is $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, functions, functional-equations

I found this problem on an Instagram page which send mostly challenging problems.

> $$\frac{f(x^2)}{f(x)}=1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^7\qquad\qquad f(x)=?$$

For $x=1$ we get $1=8$ which is a contraction hence $x=1$ should be excluded from domain of $f(x)$.
Hence we have

$$\dfrac{f(x^2)}{f(x)}=\dfrac{x^8-1}{x-1}=(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)$$ But I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: Divide and multiply the last expression by $(x - 1)(x^2  - 1)(x^4  - 1)$, and simplify the numerator. Can you see it?

Comment: What about $x = -1$? Certainly the functional equation can't hold at $x = -1$, due to the $f(x^2)$ term. Does this mean we exclude it from the domain? What are the rules here? Are we allowed further exclusions, or not? It might help to talk about how you came across this problem, so it's more clear what liberties we can and cannot take with it.

Comment: It would have been better stated as $f(x^2) = f(x)[1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^7]$, which does give some interesting simple solutions on all of $\mathbb{C}$. Instead of a contradiction, you can just conclude $f(1)=0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply use
$$x^n+1=\frac{x^{2n}-1}{x^n-1}$$
for each factor of your decomposition
$$(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1).$$

Comment: We can also multiply by any constant to get more solutions. Can we prove there are no other continuous solutions?

Comment: @aschepler If you restrict $f$ to be a polynomial, that's everything. Otherwise there are infinitely other solutions. Just take a function $g$ which satisfies $g(x)=g(x^2)$ for all $x$. Then you can extend the fraction by this $g$.